# How do I access fields within Braintree's Hosted Fields' iframes using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

On my application payment gateway is Braintree, I need to automate it and face some difficulties when I am automating it, the major problem is I cannot send credit card details using xpath, I research some tutorial for solve this and not find any good resources, please advise and guide me how I automate payment  form using selenium

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. not able to automate braintree field by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the required automation testing services, you will have to use switchTo frame as mentioned in the link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Also, for braintree the locators may differ from what you see while using inspection tool , so I will suggest to confirm the actual locators by printing the page source and checking.

You might land into domain security problem while switching to the Braintree iframe. You may try workarounds as per link,
https://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/cross-domain-iframes/

And lastly, if nothing else works you can try to find co-ordinates of the credit card text field relative to some other element that webdriver can find and then simply use sendKeys(). Something like,

Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);

actions.moveToElement(some_findable_element, x_distance_to_cc_field, x_distance_to_cc_field).click().perform();

actions.sendKeys(cc_number);